# Bad Archive when installing Ubuntu over PXE - it's looking for the Release file I do not host

Tags: ubiquity, pxe

I am trying to get Ubuntu 14.04 installed over PXE. I can get the machine to boot from network OK, the network initializes itself OK, but then I get a "BAD ARCHIVE" error and am prompted for a new mirror URL

Looking at TTY4, I can see the installer is trying to call

```
ftp://192.168.1.132/pub-ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

The IP, correctly, is that of my server; my `ks.cfg` file specifies

```
url --url ftp://192.168.1.132/pub-ubuntu
```

to identify the PXE server to pull the image contents from (that's what it's for, right?). Of course, I do not have a full package mirror on my PXE server - I am just hosting the DVD contents on the public FTP directory.

---

**My question:** Is there a way to prevent the installer from trying to reach out to online repos, or will I need to mirror the entire archive myself? I would, ideally, like to avoid that...!

Comment: If you are hosting the dvd then you should have the Release file ( it's there in the dvd ).  You must have done something simple like point it to the wrong directory.

Comment: Ay my bad - I was using a re-spun DVD :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I was installing from a re-spun DVD off of Lubuntu

I copied the dists/ directory off of a Ubuntu Server DVD of the same release and architecture and this got me past this specific roadblock.